# Using Ubuntu 10.04, is developing sites in my home folder instead of /var/www a significant security risk?

Tags: 10.04, apache2

Using advice from this [Tutorial](http://www.maketecheasier.com/install-and-configure-apache-in-ubuntu), (using a LAMP on Ubuntu 10.04) I have edited the  `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` file and originally changed both the Document Root and Directory lines from  `/var/www` to `/home/me/sites`  in my home folder, with no sudo or root privileges.

I've always just developed my sites here in this home folder, and create multiple sites and point apache to the active one using the same settings.

Is this a notable security risk?

How could I make my development process more secure using this method?

Comment: To the off topic close voter: 10.04 is not off topic if it is the server version and nothing suggest it is not ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a security risk, you may secure /home/me/sites the same way as you do /var/www. Sometimes on servers /home may be on different partition with different size than /var and disk usage or performance optimization may come to consideration.

Comment: The fact that you have to use the SUDO command to access /var/www and can manually open files in the home folder doesn't have any security effects?